# Add button to (browser) pop-up menu for html input type: file

Tags: javascript, html, css, camera

At least on Android chrome, when one touches the choose file button - to upload a file, the browser shows a little pop-up with 3 options - camera, camcorder, and file.

Is it possible for me to add a fourth option/button in there?

An example upload button is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_file).

Below is a  screenshot of the pop-up menu I'm asking about 
[image: screenshot of the pop-up menu I'm asking about]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add a fourth option to the file chooser as it is a system controlled function. Depending on what you want the fourth option to be, you could make a separate input asking for a specific thing.

URL:

< input type="url">

Specific file type:

This might be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file